# A USB 3 to M.2 Reference Design Schematic

Tags: usb, m.2

I am looking to make a small project where I need to implement a USB3 to M.2 SATA circuit for SSD interface. I am pretty confident I can follow a reference schematic and route the board, I have done this type of thing before. But I don't know where to begin in terms of finding the right components for a USB3 to M.2 SATA SSD board. Is there a place where people post open hardware reference designs? My guess is that companies that make such silicon chips that do the actual conversion would have reference documentation, but I, again, not sure where to start. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There are two problems with your question: first, questions that seek to find *external resources* are off topic.  Next it's not yet clear what functionality you are actually trying to implement - M.2 contains several distinct interfaces, it's unclear that a general solution is possible, you'll likely need to focus on what you need.  If you had, say, an LTE modem you might only need to convert the form factor of the USB interface and provide power.  If you have a storage device that speaks SATA, you'd need a USB-SATA bridge, etc...

Comment: I believe you read way more into my questions than I asked. I asked for any sort of open hardware repositories. Not sure how that kind of answer would NOT be interesting to other people reading this.

Comment: I believe you haven't read the site rules.  There are many things which are "interesting" (some perhaps even to most of the people here) which are nonetheless outside the intentionally narrow mission of this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to interface to an NVMe M.2 SSD, what you are looking for is called a USB3 to NVMe/PCIe bridge (If your M.2 was instead SATA, for example, you would be looking for a USB3 to SATA bridge).

Two USB3.1 Gen 2 to NVMe bridges that I know of are the [ASMedia ASM2362](https://www.asmedia.com.tw/eng/e_show_products.php?cate_index=195&item=196) and the [JMicron JMS583](https://www.jmicron.com/products/list/13).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I am actually looking for a USB to SATA bridge, as you proposed. The ASMedia ASM1351 appears to be just what I need, but now I need to find a sample implementation. I am searching around their site, but have yet to find something. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @inve7 I would add the [Realtek RTL9210](https://www.realtek.com/en/products/product-hits/item/ultra-high-speed-low-power-external-storage-usb-to-pcie-bridge-for-mobile-device) to that list, as showcased in this [seeedstudio article](https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2020/03/30/two-pcie-to-usb-bridge-chip-solution-to-use-nvme-ssd-on-your-raspberry-pi-4/). But as with the two others you mentioned, it is not easy to source.